# Retrofit 2.0 with GsonConverterFactory return null for fields with non-english letters in name

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I've some json, for example:

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "title": "Title",
    "photo": [
        "image.png"
    ],
    "options": {
        "Поле": "150"
    }
}
```

I create model class for parsing:

```
public class Model implements Serializable {

public int id;
public String title;
public String[] photo;
@SerializedName("option")
public Options option;

public Model(int id, String title, String[] photo, Options option) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.photo = photo;
    this.option = option;
}

public class Options implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("Поле")
    public String pole;

    public Options(String pole) {
        this.pole = pole;
    }
}
}
```

But unfortunately I have null in my Model.Option.pole.

I think, the problem is in encoding. Am I right?
And how can I solve this issue?

P.S.: In example - cyrillic name of field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is `@SerializedName("option")` should be `@SerializedName("options")` according to your json (note the plural form - option**s**)

The annotation `SerializedName` tells `gson` what it should use to serialize and deserialize the attribute key in the json. You have `options` in your json but you told `gson` to serialize and deserialize `option`.